# EF 6 Multiple Contexts in Same Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF6. I've created two namespaces for two different databases each with its own Entity Data model. In EF 3.5 when I created a model from a database the generated classes were all kept in a single file built from the context. I see in EF 6 templates are used to generate the context and the classes.

I'm running into a problem where both databases have a table which is essentially the same (version and log tables). I'm getting the following error when running a unit test to grab data from the database:

> Test method SystemDataUnitTests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception:
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not
>   valid. Errors:  The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous
>   because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'EventLog'. Previously
>   found CLR type...

I've looked up the error and I can't figure out how to go about removing one of classes and still have the whole thing work.

Comment: I believe you are hitting this: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/483. In VS2012 and VS2013 the designer by default creates POCO types and for model/database first EF is not able to handle multiple types with the same names. You could try using non-POCO types to get the same behavior you had in EF1.

Comment: @Pawel, that's exactly the problem. I just was wondering how to go about moving off the POCO models. I didn't exactly see a property on the model.

Comment: You need to delete the existing .tt templates and use the ones from: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ff479d55-2c85-43c5-a4d6-21cd659435ea?SRC=Featured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Pawel I've come up with a solution to my problem.

If you're coming from a previous version of EF as I was and want to *NOT* use EF generated POCO classes then you want to use EntityObjects. Again, to keep same functionality as older EF versions and want to upgrade to EF 6 use EF 6.x Entity Object Generator.

The best way to go about doing this is using the "Extensions and Updates" tool in VisualStudio to search for "EF 6.x EntityObject Generator".